# How to access Azure App Service folders from Function App

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is possible to access folders in the Azure App Service from the function App?

I deployed a web application on the app service, and I needed to access the saved documents from the function app.

Is it possible, and if so, kindly state.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try using [Kudu rest api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to access the folders in the Azure App Service from the function App. See below example to get a file via rest api.

```
$srcResGroupName = "ResGroupName"
$srcWebAppName = "WebAppName"
$filePath = "/site/wwwroot/myFolder/myfile.json"


# Get publishing profile for SOURCE application
$srcWebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $srcWebAppName -ResourceGroupName $srcResGroupName
[xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $srcWebApp
# Create Base64 authorization header
$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($srcWebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs"
# Download the saved file.
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl$($filePath)" `
                    -Headers @{UserAgent="powershell/1.0"; `
                     Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} `
                    -Method GET `
                    -OutFile ./myfile.json
```

You can check out [this thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-to-azure-platform-as-a-service-websites-using-kudu-rest-apis/) for more examples.

Update:

You can check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-powershell?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbrowser) to create a PowerShell function in Azure.

To run above powershell script at intervals. You need to set the [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=powershell). Please checkout [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/execute-azure-function-with-triggers/4-create-timer-trigger?pivots=csharp).

Comment: Thanks, but I know this already. What I mean is, can I access this folder setup from an Azure Function App? I deployed a web application on the app service, and I needed to access the saved documents from the function app. Is this possible?

Comment: @Dipo Kudu rest api is probably what you are looking for. Please check above update.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will check them and revert. But can I write those PowerShell scripts as triggers so it can run at intervals?

Comment: @Dipo Yes,  You can write above powershell script as azure function and setup the timer  trigger to run it at intervals. See above update.

Comment: @Dipo How is it going with this case? Does above update help your with the issue?